# Both client and server works on one file

Tags: python, sockets, client

So I have a program using sockets, it only accept connections, the server.py file listen to a client.py file, but what if I want it to do it that both files can listen and connect.

For example:
here is my server.py

```
 def main():
    print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
    """ Starting a TCP socket """
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server.bind(ADDR)

    server.listen()
    print("[LISTENING] Server is listening...")

    
    while True:
        """ Accept the connection from the client """
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        addr = socket.gethostname()
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
```

and this is my client.py

```
 def main():
    """ Staring a TCP socket. """
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while True:
        """ Connecting to the server. """
        client.connect(ADDR)
```

How can I do both of them in only one file like "Server-Client.py".
So if I want to use in one computer Server-Client.py as a client it can be use a a client,
and if I want to use Server-client.py as a server on another computer it can be use as a server and the other way around.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the server code in one function and the client code in another function. Then call the appropriate function based on whether the user asked for "client" or "server".

```
import sys

def client():
    # client code here

def server():
    # server code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'client':
        client()

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'server':
        server()
```

Comment: Thanks! only one more question, why do we need in here the "if __name__ == "__main__"":

Comment: That's the python way of asking "Is this script being executed as a main function?"